# How to display Validationerror using Data-Bind in breeze.js

Tags: breeze

I am trying to find a way to display the validation Error message right under the field being edited in a HTML Table in a fashion similar to ASP.NET(Validation Error) in MVC.

Any sample or link will be appreciated.

Here is what i have tried. It is not updating the error message immediately as I suppose it is not an observable.

```
<script id="editTmpl" type="text/html">
   <tr>
       <td><input data-bind="value: Country_Code "/>

            <div data-bind="if: $data.entityAspect.getValidationErrors().length>0">
             <pre data-bind="text:  $data.entityAspect.getValidationErrors('Country_Code')[0].errorMessage "></pre>
        </div>


       </td>
       <td><input data-bind="value: Country_Name"/></td>
        <td class="buttons">
            <a class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.save" href="#" title="save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
            <a class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.cancel" href="#" title="cancel"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
        </td>
   </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that `getValidationErrors` is not a Knockout observable. It is simply a function that returns a collection of the entity's current Breeze validation errors.

But there is an event with which you can listen for changes to that collection. Where there is an event, there's a way to create a KO observable that you can bind. Here is one way to add such an observable to an entity.

```
function addhasValidationErrorsProperty(entity) {

     var prop = ko.observable(false);

     var onChange = function () {
         var hasError = entity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors().length > 0;        
         if (prop() === hasError) {
             // collection changed even though entity net error state is unchanged
             prop.valueHasMutated(); // force notification
         } else {
             prop(hasError); // change the value and notify
         }
     };

     onChange();             // check now ...
     entity.entityAspect // ... and when errors collection changes
         .validationErrorsChanged.subscribe(onChange);

     // observable property is wired up; now add it to the entity
     entity.hasValidationErrors = prop;
}
```

Then you should be able to write something like:

```
  <div data-bind="if: hasValidationErrors">
     <pre data-bind="text: $data.entityAspect.getValidationErrors('Country_Code')[0].errorMessage "></pre>
  </div>
```

The `addhasValidationErrorsProperty` method is exercised within the "*Trigger KO computed property with validationErrorsChanged*" test in DocCode:validationTests.js

If you like it, you'll probably want to call it within an `EntityType` post-construction initializer [as discussed here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities).

**Extra Credit**

I'm not fond of

```
$data.entityAspect.getValidationErrors('Country_Code')[0].errorMessage
```

I wish I could turn that into a function of every Breeze entity but Breeze entities don't have a base type.

You can extend the prototype of a specific Breeze entity type with such a function. Perhaps the best time to do so is while you are configuring that type with the `hasValidationErrors` property.

Suppose we were working with an `Employee` entity type. Somewhere early in the application bootstrapping we could write:

```
var store = manager.metatdataStore; // one way to get the MetadataStore

// a dummy employee constructor; maybe you have a real one
var employeeCtor = function() {};

// extend its prototype with the helper method
employeeCtor.prototype.getFirstValErrMsg = function (pname) {
        var errs = this.entityAspect.getValidationErrors(pname);
        return (errs.length) ? errs[0].errorMessage : "";
    }; 

// register both the ctor and the initializer
store.registerEntityTypeCtor(
       "Employee", 
       employeeCtor,                    // custom ctor 
       addhasValidationErrorsProperty); // initializer
```

Now you should be able to bind like so:

```
  <div data-bind="if: hasValidationErrors">
     <pre data-bind="text: $data.getFirstValErrMsg('Country_Code')"></pre>
  </div>
```

I have tested pieces of this approach (e.g. the `getFirstValErrMsg` extension and the `addhasValidationErrorsProperty` method) but I haven't gotten around to the whole thing yet. Maybe you can take it the next step for us and report your findings.

Comment: The "Trigger KO computed property with validationErrorsChanged" test of DocCode:validationTests.js hasn't been deployed yet. It will be "very soon"

Comment: after Adding that ValidationError Message. i am running into problem when adding new Entity. Soon after the line, the entity is in Invalid state for Country_code Required, which is not the case                            var countryType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Country"); // [1]
                    var newCountry = countryType.createEntity(); // [2]
                    newCountry.Country_Code("India");
                    manager.addEntity(newCountry); // [3]
                    self.selectedItem(newCountry);
                    self.list.push(newCountry);